# lag in loops sound in mediaplayer android

Tags: android, audio

app have a button when user clicked button play a small sound (sound duration = 15 sec) i want loop this sound and i use this code :

```
MediaPlayer mp;
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b);
        mp.setLooping(true); 
        mp.start();
```

this work and loop my sound but with every repeat a few ms stop between every repeat sound . and this stop is very bad for my org loops sound.

I want Min Api 8 . whats best way for loop a sound without stop between repeats ?

Comment: Eli, you want to say, after first time its completed, sound stopped for some time and then repeating again...right?

Comment: Please check that the audio hasn't those part.

Comment: no i want repeat my sound unlimite . i want loop sound . but between every repeat stop sound 1ms . i want remove this stop sound between every repeat

Comment: my sound is a standard loop sound and i tested with mixcraft software and true looping

Comment: @Eli its ok, but please confirm once that, is your audio file contains that 1ms blank frame in it? there may b possibility that audio file itself have some 1ms blank frame.

Comment: setLooping Wrorking fine check your audio that content 1ms empty fream

Comment: i use standard looping sound . may this problem is my CPU ?

Comment: @Eli setLooping method is working fine as I have did it and researched it, I think some problem in your system or in your Audio file.

Comment: yes my phone is old and bad cpu :(( tnx all

Comment: @Eli hehe, its ok no problem, test with some other device, may be it will work.

Comment: my code not work good repeat sound have delay :(